# Quoted_Identifier SQL Server - Off - Unsure How

Tags: sql-server

We've been having an issue every few months where all of a sudden a job or procedure will start failing due to a quoted_Identifier issue. The quoted identifier in the proc or even table will change from 1 to 0 and we don't see any recent modified date on that record. We aren't sure how this is happening and because it's so sporadic, I can't reproduce it or trace it easily. Any ideas as to why this is occurring or what I can do to find out. I've done a lot of research without luck so far.

Thanks

Comment: You could create a DDL trigger activated by CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE events. Inside this trigger you could use EVENTDATE function to get information about SQL statements execute including ANSI)NULL and QUOTED_IDENTIFIER settings.

Comment: I don't know if the "Remarks" on this might give you a hint as to what's going on, but something must be running somewhere (by someone or as an automated task) that is resetting the value.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a DDL trigger activated by CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE events. Inside this trigger you could use EVENTDATE function to get information about SQL statements execute including ANSI_NULLS and QUOTED_IDENTIFIER settings.

For example, you could use `ddlDatabaseTriggerLog` ddl trigger from [Adventure Works OLTP database](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/) that insert into `[dbo].[DatabaseLog]` all ddl changes from current database.

DDL Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [ddlDatabaseTriggerLog] ON DATABASE 
FOR DDL_DATABASE_LEVEL_EVENTS AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;

    DECLARE @data XML;
    DECLARE @schema sysname;
    DECLARE @object sysname;
    DECLARE @eventType sysname;

    SET @data = EVENTDATA();
    SET @eventType = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'sysname');
    SET @schema = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]', 'sysname');
    SET @object = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'sysname') 

    IF @object IS NOT NULL
        PRINT '  ' + @eventType + ' - ' + @schema + '.' + @object;
    ELSE
        PRINT '  ' + @eventType + ' - ' + @schema;

    IF @eventType IS NULL
        PRINT CONVERT(nvarchar(max), @data);

    INSERT [dbo].[DatabaseLog] 
        (
        [PostTime], 
        [DatabaseUser], 
        [Event], 
        [Schema], 
        [Object], 
        [TSQL], 
        [XmlEvent]
        ) 
    VALUES 
        (
        GETDATE(), 
        CONVERT(sysname, CURRENT_USER), 
        @eventType, 
        CONVERT(sysname, @schema), 
        CONVERT(sysname, @object), 
        @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 
        @data
        );
END;
GO
```

[dbo].[DatabaseLog]

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO    
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DatabaseLog](
    [DatabaseLogID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PostTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DatabaseUser] [sysname] NOT NULL,
    [Event] [sysname] NOT NULL,
    [Schema] [sysname] NULL,
    [Object] [sysname] NULL,
    [TSQL] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [XmlEvent] [xml] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DatabaseLog_DatabaseLogID] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [DatabaseLogID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Who/when changed `dbo.uspGetEmployeeManagers` procedure ?

```
SELECT  *
FROM    [dbo].[DatabaseLog] x
WHERE   x.[Event] IN ('CREATE_PROCEDURE', 'ALTER_PROCEDURE')
AND     x.[Schema] = 'dbo'
AND     x.[Object] = 'uspGetEmployeeManagers'
```

XmlEvent column content:

```
<EVENT_INSTANCE>
  <EventType>CREATE_PROCEDURE</EventType>
...
  <TSQLCommand>
    <SetOptions ANSI_NULLS="ON" ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT="ON" ANSI_PADDING="ON" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="ON" ENCRYPTED="FALSE" />
    <CommandText>
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspGetEmployeeManagers]
    @BusinessEntityID [int]
AS
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Those scripts are helpful and I'll use them in the future. I figured out what the issue is. A stored procedure had quoted_identifier set to 0 and it had been that way for at least a year. However, someone created a filtered index on a table that the stored procedure was using. They didn't realize that the filtered index required quoted_identifier to be set to 1.